# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound Volume on iPad

Tags: ios, audio

in my application I use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound to play little caf files.
When run my app on the iPhone and I change volume by lateral buttons, the app's sound changes
 too, but on iPad the sound's volume in my app is always the same.
Maybe because on the iPhone is the ring volume, instead on the iPad is device volume.

How can I obtain same iPhone behavior on iPad?

Excuse me for my bad English....

Comment: Check your Settings on the iPad, in General -> Tap Sounds. Make sure "Change with Buttons" is set to ON.

Comment: Sounds is no longer under General but has its own settings category.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but if you change the system sounds volume with buttons all the system sounds will be modified along with your app's. I found this *really* annoying.
The solution is to use AVAudioPlayer in place of AudioServices: as easy, but way more versatile. And there you can finely tune the volume for each sound, programmatically.

```
NSURL *soundurl   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"mysound" withExtension: @"caf"];
AVAudioPlayer *mySoundPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundurl error:&error];
mySoundPlayer .volume=0.4f; //between 0 and 1
[mySoundPlayer prepareToPlay];
mySoundPlayer.numberOfLoops=0; //or more if needed

[mySoundPlayer play];
```

Comment: Does this cut out the sound being played by other apps?

Comment: Nope. Only for the sounds you define in there and inside your app.